# pytesseract ignores digits at new line

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

trying to do feature matching with opencv pytesseract ,my images are manily numbers, in some cases tesseract does not recognize digits in the new line.

Here is the image:

[image: here is the image]

The result here will be only `9804102500018` instead of `980410250001810`

so i was wondering which page segmentation mode will be the best fit to my case.

```
   image: beautify(image, pytesseract.image_to_string(
            image,
            config='--psm 6 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789',
            lang='eng'
        ))
```

this is my setting:

```
> numpy == 1.22.1
> opencv-python == 4.5.5.62
> Pillow == 8.4.0
> pytesseract == 0.3.4
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the given image, the entire content must be extracted as a single entity. You need to choose mode 8 which smeans *"Treat the image as a single word"*

Try the following:

```
image: beautify(image, pytesseract.image_to_string(
        image,
        config='--psm 8 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789',
        lang='eng'
    ))
```

For more detailed information I would recommend [this post on Pyimagesesrch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/)